# How to modify order of items in a WorkQueue before processing the items by worker thread of a k8s controller

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am having a WorkQueue like below, in which A, B and C are kubernetes resource objects:
C-A-B

I want to modify this order of the resource objects in that WorkQueue before passing those objects for processing by a worker thread, like
A-B-C

I want to do like this because there is dependency among the resource object A, B, C such that after getting the objects one by one by Get() method of WorkQueue for their processing, they should get processed in a specific order only, as they are dependent on each other.(eg. A's processing is dependent on B's processing)

Please help me for finding a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: what you are using as work queue ? Redis, RabbitMQ?

Comment: I am using a queue of type *workqueue.Type 

`type taskQueue struct {
 queue *workqueue.Type
 sync func(Task)
 workerDone chan struct{}
}`

https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/util/workqueue

Comment: @NehaKembalkar, please provide us more information about your WorkQueue, it's deployment and etc. What is the Kubernetes version you're using?